# is it possible to make a discord bot add an emoji to a server? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I want to make a bot that adds a single emoji to a server but I am not sure if a bot can do that.
I have looked at the documentation and haven't found much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, discord bots can not add new emojis to a server, they can only react with them and detect reactions of emojis